# Google search appears out of nowhere

Tags: google-search

From time to time Google (voice) search randomly starts on my phone ([Huawei Ascend Y300](http://www.gsmarena.com/huawei_ascend_y300-5386.php), Android version 4.1.1). I'll be listening to music for example, change song, and out of nowhere Google voice search will open. I have no idea what button I'm pressing or what I'm doing to activate this. I would ideally deactivate this completely, but knowing what it is I do to open this will also be of great help.

I've gone to the settings when I get this screen. Google Now is already turned off and there doesn't seem to be anything relevant there I can do.

[image: Screenshot]
<sup>Screenshot (click for larger variant)</sup>

Comment: Hi, what type of phone is it? Different devices have different shortcuts on them, not usually to voice search but yours might. E.g. on Samusng holding menu is the shortcut to Google Search, holding home is shortcut to app manager etc. It MIGHT be something simple like that, the capacative buttons are VERY easy to press against and any sweat/moisture can cause them to register a long press. Failing that maybe uninstall and reinstall search/voice search. But try holding buttons etc, check your phone manual.

Comment: I have a Huawei Ascend Y300. It only has six buttons; the top to turn it on and off, two volume buttons, and the back, home, and settings buttons. It sometimes seems there's a magical hidden button somewhere that I keep pressing...

Comment: It appears you are not alone with this issue and it is a bug in the device itself: http://androidforums.com/huawei-ascend-y300/795270-permanently-disable-google-voice-y300.html You may need to turn off voice search, which is going to be a problem potentially as it is part of Google Search. http://www.modaco.com/topic/368392-twisting-earphone-plug-opens-google-search-wtf/ here also, may be related to headphones, but nothing conclusive.

Comment: Long press back and settings buttons do the same as short press. Long press home button gets me a list of recent apps. It's the same on the home screen and when playing music.

Comment: @RossC Thank you for that link! Still annoying but at least I'm not the only one. I'll try disabling voice search.

Comment: @RossC That should be an answer, not a comment.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This Google Voice Search pop up appears to be a bug in the Huawei Ascend Y300 model. From  [This thread on Android Forums](http://androidforums.com/huawei-ascend-y300/795270-permanently-disable-google-voice-y300.html) that you are not alone with the issue but there is no resolution in the thread.

Further reading in [This modaco thread](http://www.modaco.com/topic/368392-twisting-earphone-plug-opens-google-search-wtf/) that it might be related to the headphones causing something in the device to trigger Voice Search rather than the intended result e.g. skipping song, changing volume etc.

One user (referring to the headphones) states:

> "I get this all the damn time on my Y300. In my case it's Voice Search that opens (I'm on CM11) and I tried renaming the VoiceSearch.apk in /system/app/ (IIRC) but still it comes up.
>
> It's probably getting the contacts confused and triggering that third button on some headsets, but it's bloody annoying."

The fact he is using CyanogenMod and not the stock ROM suggests a Hardware issue rather than a software one.

You could attempt to disable Google Voice search while listening to music as a workaround, althought it is part of Search itself and this may be inconvenient on a day to day basis.

Comment: I think it's because of a compatibility issue in the TRRS socket. The call button in headphones functions by shorting two of the contacts, and long-pressing the call button starts voice search. If the headphone plug doesn't fit the jack properly, it might cause the short to happen involuntarily.